# Why is a comma used here when paraphrasing a talking point?

Tags: commas

I was reading this article, and I came across this sentence:

> In a quieter response, the University of Minnesota announced that it was immediately limiting its links with the Minneapolis Police **Department, saying** its Minneapolis campus would no longer contract with the department for extra security support.

I was analyzing the grammar of the bolder area, and I couldn’t figure out why there was a comma. Let me know if you guys can figure it out. Thanks

Comment: What follows is nonrestrictive information. It's additional, and could be deleted without affecting the essential meaning of the sentence. (The same is true of the text the precedes the first comma.)

Comment: Thanks, I understand now :)